# Weird bluetooth deviceClass is being returned by bluetooth event: 240404

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using a broadcast receiver to try to find when a bluetooth headphone is connect/disconnected to an android device.

```
 val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
```

And I handle the event in this way:

```
   device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
   val major = device?.bluetoothClass?.majorDeviceClass;
   val bluetoothClass = device?.bluetoothClass ?: return
```

What I get is

- `major` as `1024` (that is `BluetoothClass.Device.Major.AUDIO_VIDEO` which is correct)
- `bluetoothClass.deviceClass` as `240404` but [it is not listed as any of the recognized Bluetooth Devices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device#AUDIO_VIDEO_HEADPHONES).

[image: 240404]
Am I using the wrong property to compare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So silly me, I **was** comparing the wrong thing. What I have to compare is the [`deviceClass` property inside `bluetoothClass`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass#getDeviceClass())